# Save content from text field when moving between view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a view which is pushed from another view. That second view has a text field. If I modified anything in the text field, that content is not present once I go back and then forward again. How can I save those data before the second view is popped up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is with file persistence. Basically when you are exiting your second view, you need to write the data in the text field to a file and then read from this file when opening the second view.

My iOS is a little rusty but i think it would be something like this:

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
          -code to read from file
          -and display in text field
    }

    -(void)viewDidUnload {
          -code to save to file from text field
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly you need to save the data when you back and come again.Then you need to take a variable in first screen and send data while you are going back and push that data into second screen when come again.

In first screen take a variable like TextFieldData and synthesize it and when writing the code to go back to the first screen from second screen write like this
    FirstScreen *first = [[FirstScreen alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:first animated:YES];
    [setTextFieldData:textField.text];
    [first release];
do the same way while come back to second screen.

Comment: As I am new to IOS, Can you tell me is there any obj c way of saving that data, or do we need to follow normal setting and getting C++ concept?

Comment: If we alloc new object for first screen, then it won't be our existing object right? IF we set like what you done above, it won't be stored in our first screen existing object?

Comment: FirstScreen:UIViewController{NSString *textObj;}@Property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *textObj;and in .m file you need to synthesize it.then it works charm.